# React Router - How to redirect user if logged in?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom to manage my routes:

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={Navbar} />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
          <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={DashboardRoutes} />
          <Route path="*" component={() => <h1>Page not found</h1>} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={Footer} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

I want only to render the `Navbar` if the user is not authenticated. If the user is authenticated, I don't want to render the `Navbar` and I want to redirect him to dashboard.

I tried with inline conditioning:

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        {!isAuthenticated() && <Route path="/" component={Navbar} />}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
          <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={DashboardRoutes} />
          <Route path="*" component={() => <h1>Page not found</h1>} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={Footer} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

However, when I'm not logged in, and then sign in, the `Navbar` persists, because it was rendered when `isAuthenticated` was false.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

PS: I already have a `isAuthenticated` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to handle this would be in your Navbar component itself.

In your Navbar component, setup `componentDidMount()` to check if the user isAuthenticated and just redirect them.

```
componentDidMount(){
    if(isAuthenticated()){
        this.props.history.push("/dashboard")
    }
}
```

And in the render(), just use the `isAuthenticated`() method you set up to determine if you should return anything.

```
render(){
   if(!isAuthenticated()){
     return(
        ...your navbar markup
     ) else {
        return null
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Instead of `componentDidMount()` I used `useEffect` with an empty array. It worked like a charm

Comment: Awesome dude! ive been wanting to learn more about hooks. Im glad that it works there too :)

Comment: It's pretty easy. I guess it's easier than using Redux to manage global states, at least the code is less verbose