# redirect to login page when user is not authenticated

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom

I want to redirect to login page when user is not authenticated.
I can check this is `componentDidMount` but it doesn't have good UX.
How can I do this with react router dom?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router - How to redirect user if logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353125/react-router-how-to-redirect-user-if-logged-in)

Comment: I said in my question `componentDidMount` it doesn't have good UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Redirect` and privateRoute.
PriveRoute component:

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...props }) {
  const isAuthenticated = true or false;
  return (
    <Route
      render={props =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

and use it in your `BrowserRouter`:

```
<PrivateRoute
    exact
    path='/home'
    component={<Home />}
/>
```

you can check authenticated in PrivateRoute with redux or whatever you like.